# SignalR json_aot protocol

Tags: asp.net, json, signalr, protocols

I am currently working on a server which uses SignalR next to plain HTTP for communication.
I created a Asp.Net Core 5.0 backend with SignalR and implemented some methods to invoke the client calls.

**I have no plain sources of the client.**

But now I have a problem. I can´t connect from the client to the server because the server doesn´t understand the SignalR protocol from the client.

```
[Microsoft.AspNetCore.SignalR.Client.HubConnection], Error starting connection., Microsoft.AspNetCore.SignalR.HubException: Unable to complete handshake with the server due to an error: The protocol 'json_aot' is not supported.
```

Maybe I am just dumb but I can´t find the protocol "json_aot" anywhere on the internet.
On the official Asp.Net github page there are some protocols like [this](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/blob/371bf375f5bf6e48ab6b33e24ad0c73a940b4ae4/src/SignalR/common/Protocols.NewtonsoftJson/src/Protocol/NewtonsoftJsonHubProtocol.cs#L37) but this protocol has the name "json".
I know that the client uses the following HubConnectionBuilder extension:

```
Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.NewtonsoftAotProtocolDependencyInjectionExtensions.AddNewtonsoftAotProtocol<object>
```

This sounds like something official from Newtonsoft but the only SignalR Newtonsoft protocol i found is the one mentioned above.

Does anyone know that protocol or has any other idea how I can solve that problem.

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

It's a bit odd that you're using something that you don't know where it's coming from. AddNewtonsoftAotProtocol is not something official from Microsoft.

SignalR does some negotiation when a connection attempts to connect, this involves figuring out what common protocol the server and client can speak. In your case you're using some random package on the client that speaks "json_aot". The server isn't aware of this protocol by default and thus will reject the connection attempt. There are a few things you can do:

1. Try to find the owner of AddNewtonsoftAotProtocol and see if they have a good reason for using a unique protocol name instead of "json". If they are writing normal json then they should be fine keeping the protocol name as "json" and things will just work.
2. Configure the server to use AddNewtonsoftAotProtocol. If it's programmed similarly to the official SignalR protocols, then the same code should be usable on the server and client. This will teach the server about the "json_aot" protocol and your client will be able to connect.
3. Write a wrapper around the official JsonHubProtocol implementation and set the protocol name to "json_aot". Assuming AddNewtonsoftAotProtocol outputs normal json this should just work.